# Нужно соединить двух братьев в один элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<div>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Есть два брата, помогите , есть ли метод который с помощью **jquery** , соединяет их в один братский `<ul>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572760/combining-multiple-uls-into-one-ul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var ul = $('.siblings');
ul.parent().html($('<ul>').addClass('siblings').append(ul.find('li')));
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue;
}
li {
  background: blue;
}

.siblings {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

В данном случае у `ul` не будет класса. Но если нужно - можно добавить.

---

Еще

```js
$('ul.siblings').not(':first').remove().children('li').appendTo('ul:first');
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue;
}
li {
  background: blue;
}

.siblings {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста в примере к ul класс

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович добавил. ну и вариант с enSO добавил

Comment: а чтобы вернуть , например при разрешении экрана > 760px, в начальную структуру DOM, как будет выглядить код?

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович значит надо куда-то сохранять.... либо через какие-нибудь флексы в css делать. это надо смотреть что нужно. так можно бесконечно придумывать условия

Comment: @stckvrw у вас ложные данные

Comment: А каким образом сохранить в переменную структуру DOM? подскажите каким образом это сделать,а дальше я уже доделаю сам

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович ну например `var divHtml = $('.siblings').parent().html();`

Comment: человеческое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

А если просто:

```
$('div').html($('div').html().replace(/<\/ul>\n\s\s<ul class="siblings">\n\s\s/g,''));
```